# Why can I not install Node with Homebrew?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, homebrew

I was able to download homebrew successfully. However, whenever I use 'brew install node' , I am getting the error message:

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
You can try again using:
  brew link node
```

I have also tried 'brew link node' which results in:

```
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the official [troubleshooting page of Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html). You have to give Homebrew the right to write inside `/usr/local`. To do this the official command to run is:

```
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var opt Cellar Caskroom Frameworks
```

If you have not installed applications in `/usr/local` that rely on specific permissions, you can also run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*
```